# Pass ng-content into another component as ng-content

Tags: angular, ng-content, angular-content-projection

I have got `CollapsibleComponent` which uses `CollapsibleActionsComponent` in it. I would like to be able to pass additional action buttons into `CollapsibleActionsComponent` through `CollapsibleComponent` as shown in example:

`CollapsibleActionsComponent`:

```
<div class="actions">
  <ng-content></ng-content> // this is where I would expect "Additional button" to be projected
  <button>Common button</button>
</div>
```

`CollapsibleComponent`:

```
<div class="header">
  ...
 
  <app-collapsible-actions>
    <ng-content select="[slot=moreCustomActions]"></ng-content>
  </app-collapsible-actions>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <ng-content select="[slot=body]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

`AppComponent`:

```
<app-collapsible>
  <div slot="moreCustomActions">
    <button>Additional button</button>
  </div>

  <div slot=body>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</app-collapsible>
```

The additional button is not shown. This is probably duplicate of some previous question, but I was not able to find it.

During writing this question I realized that I can get rid of the `CollapsibleActionsComponent` and move it up into `CollapsibleComponent` because I am not using it elsewhere. However let's assume I would use it.

Comment: You forgot double quotes in `select=[slot=moreCustomActions]`, should be `select="[slot=moreCustomActions]"`

Comment: @MehdiShakeri thanks, that was just mistake in writing. updated.